# Override SpringBatch jobLauncher with command line arguments

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have override `jobLauncher()` in BatchConfig in my SpringBatchapplication as follow:

```
 @Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher() throws SQLException {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher() {
        JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("param1", "ABC")
                .addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis())
                .toJobParameters();

        @Override
        public JobExecution run(Job job, JobParameters jobParameters) throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException {
            return super.run(job, params);
        }
    };

    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRepository());

    return jobLauncher;
}
```

However, now I want `param1` to be passed in as a command line argument. Is this possible while overriding `jobLauncher()` at the same time?

Comment: Why do you create job parameters as an instance variable of your custom JobLauncher then use them in the run method instead of the ones that are passed to the command line? This will ignore any parameter passed to your job via the command line. Can you explain what are you trying to achieve? I will try to help you do it in the correct way.

Comment: Do you actually need to implement your own `JobLauncher`?  All you are customizing is the `JobParameters` you are passing in during construction.  You could just as easily create a method that will build a `JobParameters` object and pass that in to the default `JobLauncher` along with your `Job`.

Comment: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55931561/9260161